# area locations nearby using reverse geocoding provide different results

Tags: reverse-geocoding

I am using googles reverse geocoding to lookup sub localities and neighbourhoods.

Both of the below coordinates are extremely close to one another and are both within victoria island in Nigeria however only the first reference shows the neighbourhood.

Shows vitoria island in the response under neighbourhoods

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=6.428291386098148,3.4191928832085523&sensor=false

Doesn't show victoria island in the response under neighbourhoods from the first address components

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=6.427779639540112,3.420051190093318&sensor=false

Can anyone shed some light on this? Is there a way to get better results? I have tried yahoo place finder but no luck there either.